# Finding a pointwise convergent sequence that does not converge in the square mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pointwise-convergence

I am having a tough time finding a function sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of continuous functions of $[0,1] \to \mathbb K$, whereby $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R,\mathbb C\}$, such that $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise but does not converge in quadratic mean.

My ideas: Since $\forall x \in [0,1]: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\to 0, n\to \infty.$

Basically I'm trying to find a $C>0$, such that $\int^{1}_{0}|(f_{n}-f)(x)|^{2}dx\geq\int^{1}_{0}C^{2}dx \neq0. 
 $

Any hints for suited functions?

Comment: What if you consider continuous "triangle" type functions with a thin base and very large heights?

Comment: How do I construct these triangle type functions?

Comment: Let $f_n$ be the "triangle function" whose graph connects the points $(0,0),(1/n,n^2),(2/n,0),(1,0)$ with line segments. Then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise. Note $f_n(x) = n^2x$ on $[0,1/n].$ Thus $\int_0^1 f_n^2 \ge \int_0^{1/n} f_n^2 = \int_0^{1/n}n^4x^2\,dx \to \infty.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$f_n = 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{n\pi\sin(n\pi x)} \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq \dfrac{1}{n} \\
0 \text{ for } \dfrac{1}{n} < x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $0$. To see this, note that for any $c \in (0, 1]$, then for all $k > \frac{1}{c}$,

$$f_k(c) = 0$$

Moreover, $f_k(0)$ is always $0$.

However, $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $0$ on the quadratic mean. It is easy to see that

$$\int_{0}^{1} f_k^2(x) \, dx = 2 \neq 0$$

always.

[For visual intuition, view here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbmrfbmnjt)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $f_n(x) = n\sqrt {x^n(1-x)}$ converges pointwise to $0$ everywhere on $[0,1],$ but $\int |f_n-0|^2 \to 1.$